# Deployed Keycloak Script Mapper does not show up in the GUI

Tags: keycloak

I'm using the docker image of Keycloak 10.0.2. I want Keycloak to supply access_tokens that can be used by Hasura. Hasura requires custom claims like this:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "admin": true,
  "iat": 1516239022,
  "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["editor","user", "mod"],
    "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
    "x-hasura-user-id": "1234567890",
    "x-hasura-org-id": "123",
    "x-hasura-custom": "custom-value"
  }
}
```

Following the documentation, and using a script I found online, (See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/webdeb/d8a99df9023f01b78e3e8ff580abe10b)) I created a Script Mapper jar with this script (copied verbatim from the gist), in `hasura-mapper.js`:

```
var roles = [];
for each (var role in user.getRoleMappings()) roles.push(role.getName());
token.setOtherClaims("https://hasura.io/jwt/claims", {
    "x-hasura-user-id": user.getId(),
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": Java.to(roles, "java.lang.String[]"),
    "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
});
```

and the following `keycloak-scripts.json` in META-INF/:

```
{
    "mappers": [
        {
            "name": "Hasura",
            "fileName": "hasura-mapper.js",
            "description": "Create Hasura Namespaces and roles"
        }
    ]
}
```

Keycloak debug log indicates it found the jar, and successfully deployed it.
But what's the next step? I can't find the deployed mapper anywhere in the GUI, so how do I activate it? I tried creating a protocol Mapper, but the option 'Script Mapper' is not available. And Scopes -> Evaluate generates a standard access token.

How do I activate my deployed protocol mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course after you put up a question on SO you still keep searching, and I finally found the answer in this [JIRA issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12511). The scripts feature has been a preview feature since (I think) version 8.

So when starting Keycloak you need to provide:

```
 -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled
```

and after that your Script Mapper will show up in the Mapper Type dropdown on the Create Mapper screen, and everything works.

Comment: Eventually, you can still enable deprecated `upload_scripts` feature and you can define scripts directly in the UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118667/keycloak-9-0-2-missing-script-mapper

Comment: I know, but it's in a docker container, so if that is refreshed won't I lose my uploaded file?

Comment: No, mapper definition is saved in the DB, not on the filesystem. I would use deprecated upload_scripts feature for quick development and then jar file for final deployment.

Comment: I believe this only works for WildFly distributions. Note that certain versions of Keycloak have both WildFly and Quarkus distributions.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the `scripts` feature for [Quarkus based distributions](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus), you have to use the `--features` startup flag.

For container packaged by [RedHat](https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak)

```
docker run quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest [start|start-dev] --features=scripts
```

For container packaged by [Bitnami](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/keycloak/)

```
docker run bitnami/keycloak:latest -e KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS="--features=scripts"
```