# Auth0 rules option in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, auth0

I am new to Keycloak. I was working on auth0 and in auth0 we have rules (part of the authentication pipeline). In rules, we could have custom Javascript files and code needed to complete the process.
https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules

so is there anything in the keycloak that will provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

See [Protocols Mappers](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_protocol-mappers) - there is many types of mappers and of them is [Script mapper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#script-mapper), where you can script some additional functionality.

Comment: I am unable to see mapper of mentioned type. is there any thing I have to do while deploying keycloak? [![mapper.png](https://i.postimg.cc/0yZNP7Wd/mapper.png)](https://postimg.cc/21bYxLfV)

Comment: @WaqasAhmad that "scripting" feature must be enabled explicitly, so check doc of used Keycloak version (it is version specific!) For example older Keycloak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118667/keycloak-9-0-2-missing-script-mapper

Comment: it is deprecated feature so will it cause any issue??

Comment: @WaqasAhmad it is your decision. You can use "script" to write custom functionality + you need to keep in mind that scripting feature may be removed in the future release. Or you can write decent Java code - SPI (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html) which will create additional Keycloak native mapper for your needs - of course you will need more dev time/skills for SPI.